# How to show notifications at provided time frame and frequency in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to make a feature where user can select the time frame and interval in which he would receive notifications to his phone. I'm using `AlarmManager` for repeating notifications, however it only covers the start time of notifications and the interval/frequency of notifications.

How could I make the notifications go off only from user selected hours, let's say every day 1 PM - 8 PM (13:00 - 20:00) every 2 hours?

I was thinking about using `WorkManager` to start `AlarmManager` at selected start hour and to cancel `AlarmManager` on user selected end hour, that way `WorkManager` would handle the everyday start/end hours and `AlarmManager` would send a notification with provided frequency. But I'm not sure if it's a "correct" approach.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think what you are proposing would work, but another option is to us a non-repeating alarm that sets the next alarm according to the users desired schedule that is persisted some how (e.g. shared preferences).